# Selenium 4 Network Logging Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium4

Between all versions out I seem to not understand something.
I'm running selenium version 4.0.0

I have tried to run:

```
options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {'performance': 'ALL'})
```

with the following result:

> Message: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found (Session
> info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)

My objective:
Log the sent requests and it's responses in PYTHON for selenium i have only found JAVA examples, please help

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

I use (options omitted):

```
d = {}
d['goog:perfLoggingPrefs'] = {'enableNetwork': True}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=d)
```

(but in chromium/chrome canary I think this is on per default, because it works
even with desired_capabilities=None)

It returns a list of dicts which you can sort on `'source'=='network'`:

```
chromelog = driver.get_log('browser')
time.sleep(2) # must sleep to get activity
print([l for l in chromelog if l['source']=='network'])
```

Giving:

```
[{'level': 'SEVERE', 'message': 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)', 'source': 'network', 'timestamp': 1663936185792}]
```

using `selenium==4.4.3` and `chromium==107.0.5283.0`